# Online ticket website confirmed order but didn't deliver tickets + charge my credit card so I bought again

Tags: credit-card, ecommerce

This live event ticketing website confirmed my order but it got sent to my spam. Since I didn't notice it in my inbox and saw no credit card transaction for it, I bought it again. Now I'm scared that I'll be double charged for an event that is all sales final. The same platform previously had sent me my tickets within the same hour with the scannable barcode but this time failed to do so.

I locked my credit card so I'm wondering if that would be a workaround way to cancel the transaction that is "all sales final".

Comment: Try emailing support and explain what has happened. Most reasonable companies would rather have a happy customer and deliver outstanding support than earn one more ticket sale and get a grumpy customer who made a mistake

Comment: You twice state that the vendor failed to send you the tickets, but you also state that it got sent to your spam. How are these two claims compatible?

Answer (score 8):

If the vendor failed to deliver the order, you could contact the credit card company and have them "charge back" the purchase price.

But here, they did deliver it; you simply failed to look in the right mailbox. That really isn't their fault, and a charge back is not permitted.

You could play clueless and try anyway, though that's fraud. But I'm sure this happens frequently enough that the ticketing service is well known to the credit card companies and has a standard response to this.

You could also pretend your credit card was stolen and try to refuse payment that way. Again, fraud.

You made a mistake. It happens. Own it and learn from it.

Re asking the vendor to make an exception: The vendor is probably not the venue, so they've already passed the money along except for their fee (which one hopes is a relatively small amount).

However: If the ticket date is still in the future, you can try asking the venue if they would be willing to try reselling your extra tickets. You might or might not get the cash back, but if they're a nonprofit they might write you a letter saying that you donated back the tickets, letting you try to deduct that on your taxes.

Or, again if there's still time, you might be able to pass the excess tickets along to a friend. Or find some way to resell them.

If the date has already come and gone, though, I don't think you're likely to be able to recover any of this. File it under education or confusion tax...

Comment: You could also try asking the vendor nicely to make an exception.